# Meaning of "and there to create"

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> You can now go to the web version - Lingualeo 
>   **and there to create** your own personal Word Sets.
>   For example - 
>   After synchronization, Word Sets will be available in the application in the section

I couldn't figure out the meaning of the meaning of the bold part. What's the meaning of **there to create** in this sentence?

Comment: I think : " and you can create there "

Comment: I suspect that the sentence previously started with something like "It is possible to go... " or "You are welcome to go ... ", and somebody edited that bit without noticing that they needed to change the grqammar after the "and".

Comment: Drop the 'to' and it works ok (and there create), if a bit wordy.